# How to View image from cameraroll/camera in a new view controller

Tags: ios, imageview, viewcontroller

Ok so i have created an app that takes a picture from camera or camera roll and i can display the image after selecting it in the same view controller. what i want to do is get the picture and load it in a new view controller so i can have a new tool bar that can add overlay images to it

this is my button code

```
- (IBAction) useCameraRoll:(id)sender
{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                       animated:YES completion:nil];
    _newMedia = NO;

}
}
```

this is my SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property BOOL newMedia;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
- (void)useCamera:(id)sender;
- (void)useCameraRoll:(id)sender;
@end
```

---

Ok having some more problems, I've put in the code suggested, but nothing new is happening in my simulator here is my entire code i wonder if anyone can help me
    //
    //  BESPOKEViewController.m
    //  Shelf Planner
    //
    //  Created by AppyWorld on 26/04/2014.
    //  Copyright (c) 2014 AppyWorld. All rights reserved.
    //

```
#import "BESPOKEViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface BESPOKEViewController ()

@end

@implementation BESPOKEViewController





- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}// The method that gets called when you want to present the second view controller

- (void)showSecondViewControllerButton:(id)sender
{
UIImage *imageToDisplay = self.imageView.image;

SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
secondViewController.image = imageToDisplay;

// Or present it another way
[self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (IBAction) useCamera:(id)sender
{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                       animated:YES completion:nil];
    _newMedia = YES;
    }
}
- (IBAction) useCameraRoll:(id)sender
{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                       animated:YES completion:nil];
    _newMedia = NO;

  }
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];






if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    _imageView.image = image;
    if (_newMedia)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                       self,


  @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                        nil);


  }
 else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
  {
    // Code here to support video if enabled
  }
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                          message: @"Failed to save image"
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
@end
```

here is my SVC.m

```
 //
 //  Created by AppyWorld on 26/04/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 AppyWorld. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
// You override the setter so that the image you give it gets displayed in the image         

view
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
_image = image;



}- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation       before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Thanks in advance

If u want any other code please let me know :)

Comment: "The same view controller", do you mean the `UIImagePickerController` or the (custom) view controller that presented it?

Comment: i meant that i have set an UIImageView in my FirstViewController but i want to move it to a secondViewController

Comment: Well, I don't know what your code looks like, but maybe you can add a `UIImage` property to that view controller. First you initilize the view controller, then you set the image property, then you present it.

Comment: ive added the code i think you need, sorry i am very new to this, started 4 days ago and i have no coding background

Comment: No need to apologize :) assuming that you have a working `UIImageView` in your _first_ view controller, set the `image` property of your _second_ view controller in the code that you use to present that view controller.

Comment: By the way, you can access the image of a `UIImageView` by doing this: `yourImagePicker.image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/) will be more than enough ;)

Comment: i used the tutorial, it does everything i want but, after i select a picture from the cameraroll and press choose, it loads the image in the same view as the firstview, and i have the buttons from that view still in the screen (at the bottom (Take photo and Select Photo)) i want it to load on a new screen so i can add a new option to add overlay images ontop of the image i just selected

Comment: Have I understood you correctly, _after_ you take a picture, you want to have that picture in another view that gets presented?

Comment: Yes that is correct, i want it displayed in a new viewcontroller so i can add a new toolbar on the view controller and in that tool bar i want to have images that i can drag to the picture as an overlay... like many apps out there that you can put cartoon lips/glasses ect on pictures of people

Answer (score 0):

**SecondViewController.h**

```
@interface secondViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;

// Other properties here...

@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
// You override the setter so that the image you give it gets displayed in the image view
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    _image = image;

    self.imageView.image = image;
}
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                               completion:nil];

    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    secondVC.image = chosenImage;

    [self presentViewController:secondVC
                       animated:YES
                     compeltion:nil];
}
```

This method gets called when the image picker finishes. Don't forget to set `self` as the delegate of the image picker when the image picker gets presented.